# Counting entries by sub-categories and date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I'm trying to count the number of people who've joined a group by date. So this:

```
individual_id   group_id     date  
   a              1       2000-01-01  
   a              1       2000-01-02  
   a              1       2000-01-03  
   b              1       2000-01-02  
   b              1       2000-01-04  
   c              1       2000-01-03  
   c              1       2000-01-04  
   d              2       2000-01-02
```

Would become this:

```
individual_id   group_id     date      people_in_group
   a              1       2000-01-01         1
   a              1       2000-01-02         2
   a              1       2000-01-03         3
   b              1       2000-01-02         2
   b              1       2000-01-04         3
   c              1       2000-01-03         3
   c              1       2000-01-04         3
   d              2       2000-01-02         1
```

Comment: Could you confirm that this is `Panel` datatype? As it's 2-D, I would have expected it to be a `DataFrame`

Comment: I've posted an answer, but I don't think it's what you want.  I'm officially confused!!  The dates 2000-01-05 and 2000-01-06 appear in the original dataframe, but not in the result - can you explain why?  Can you explain what the multiple rows with the same `individual_id` and `group_id` mean?  I took it to mean that the same person was joining a group on multiple occasions, but now think that might be wrong.

Comment: Ugg. Horrible typo; so sorry! Should be the same between the two. The reason there are multiple rows is that this is a panel with multiple observations over the same individual. In my dataset there are other important variables that I need to track. Each individual should only be counted once. On 2000-01-01 there is only one person in the group, a, but on 2000-01-03 there are three people in the group: a, b, and c.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use GroupBy to find out how many joined ***on*** each date - i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'individual_id':['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','d'],
                   'group_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2],
                   'date':[datetime(2000,01,01),datetime(2000,01,02),
                           datetime(2000,01,03),datetime(2000,01,05),
                           datetime(2000,01,06),datetime(2000,01,03),
                           datetime(2000,01,04),datetime(2000,01,02)]})

#df = <dataframe of your original data (mocked up above)>
#Add a placeholder 'rowCounter' column, so that the groups are easily counted.
df['rowCounter'] = np.ones(len(df))    
df1  = df.groupby(['individual_id','group_id','date'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Then, use `cumsum()` function to total them up to and including the date

```
df1['people_in_group'] = df1.groupby(['individual_id','group_id'], as_index=False)['rowCounter'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
```

Optionally, remove the dummy row counter column we created:

```
df1 = df1.drop('rowCounter',1)
```

A print of df1 now shows

```
  individual_id  group_id       date  people_in_group
0             a         1 2000-01-01                1
1             a         1 2000-01-02                2
2             a         1 2000-01-03                3
3             b         1 2000-01-05                1
4             b         1 2000-01-06                2
5             c         1 2000-01-03                1
6             c         1 2000-01-04                2
7             d         2 2000-01-02                1
```

Comment: Thanks. Little confused by this answer. If you include 'date' in the first groupby, you get an empty dataframe. Maybe you're skipping some steps.

Comment: Sorry - the perils of dropping an answer in without testing first.  I'll put a more complete answer up in a moment - there are some errors in what I put up making it nonsense.

Comment: In fact - just realised I've misunderstood the question - I could post what I was driving at, but I no longer think it's what you want.  I'll request clarification in a comment under the original question.